# C# CodeFunction2 - How do you prevent creation of 'return'?

Tags: c#, code-generation, vsx

I am creating a C# class as per:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6h10s6x.aspx

however I want my own 'return' rather than the  `return default(int);` it automatically generates. I know I can insert my own text using an EditPoint i.e

```
 editPoint.Insert("return records.AsEnumerable<" + tableNameAsSingular + ">();");
```

but it still tries to stick in its own 'return' too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround can be to delete of the default content of the method:

```
TextPoint startPoint = method.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody);
TextPoint endPoint = method.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody);

var editPoint = startPoint.CreateEditPoint();
editPoint.Delete(endPoint);
```

This code should erase the default content of the method.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I should ask another question but... Do you know the best way to add using statements with EnvDte?

Comment: You can add it as text :
var editPoint = applicationObject.ActiveDocument.GetTextDocument().CreateEditPoint(TextDocument.StartPoint);
editPoint.Insert("using System;");

Answer (score 0):

In CodeDOM, there is something like CodeMethodReturnStatement.  There may be something similar in VS code generation extensibility.